# Generic type definitions in angular components with parent/child relations

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to create a component like this:

```html
<dropdown formControlName="car">
  <dropdown-option value="volvo"></dropdown-option>
  <dropdown-option value="bmw"></dropdown-option>
  <dropdown-option value="peugeot"></dropdown-option>
  <!-- etc -->
</dropdown>
```

My definition for the dropdown component is as follows:

```ts
export component DropdownComponent<T> {
  possibilities: Array<T>
}
```

My definition for dropdown option component is as follows:

```ts
export component DropdownOptionComponent<T> {
  @Input() value: T
}
```

Is it possible that my `DropdownOptionComponent` can infer generic type `T` of `DropdownComponent` and restrict the available options for `DropdownOptionComponent` to whatever satisfies the generic `T`?

Edit: To further clarify what I want to have resolved, I want my template to be smart enough to see that given the parent definition, in my template, it will check if it is valid.

Edit 2: Better example:

```
// mycomponent.component.ts
export class MyComponent {
  data: Array<{param1: number, param2: string}>;
}
```

```html
<!-- mycomponent.component.html -->
<table [dataSource]="data">
  <table-entry *myTemplateDirective="let entry">
    <!-- do something with entry -->
  </table-entry>
</table>
```

Is it possible to get `entry` typed based on the input of `data` in the table component.

Edit 3: Typo in code example

Answer (score 0):

Even though you declare your child component has a generic type when you are passing value from parent component to child component you by default get the exact type which was used in the parent component itself. you don't need to do explicitly again.

If you look at the below example the moment you declared the value of the property with a boolean value. Typescript will able to tell what type that property is associated with, in a similar fashion it will work for your use case as well

[image: Example Type Casting]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, you are indeed correct about this behavior, and this could be a valid solution for the scenario I sketched.

However, I am trying to solve a typing issue in the template, and your answer does not specifically solve that

Comment: Can you be more specific about the use case what typing issue you are trying to solve in template ?

Comment: I clarified my question with a better example

Comment: Same question here